# Box2DDebugRenderer and SpriteBatch misplaced

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am playing with libgdx for making yet another physics game :) and I have found something weird. Namely I use SpriteBatch for rendering images at the same time with Box2DDebugRenderer for debuging.

But when the physics acts, they appear to be misplaced. I wrote:

```
public class Canon implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;

    /...
public void create() {              
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    world = new World(new Vector2(0f, -9.8f), true);
        camera.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, 0f); 
        camera.update();        
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        //Create a canon. A rectangle :)
        bd = new BodyDef();
    fd = new FixtureDef(); fd.density = 1;
    PolygonShape ps = new PolygonShape();

    // Cannon
    bd.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bd.position.set(new Vector2(8, 5));
    ps.setAsBox(5f, 1f);
    cannonBody = world.createBody(bd);
    fd.shape = ps;
    cannonBody.createFixture(fd);
    }

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    world.step(BOX_STEP, BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS);  
        spriteBatch.begin();
        Sprite s = (Sprite)targetBody1.getUserData();
        spriteBatch.draw(s.getTexture(), 
            (targetBody1.getPosition().x - bodyWidth/2)*ppuX,            (targetBody1.getPosition().y - bodyheight/2)*ppuY,
            0f, 0f, bodyWidth*ppuX, bodyheight*ppuY, 1f, 1f, radToGrad*targetBody1.getAngle(), 0, 0, s.getTexture().getWidth(), s.getTexture().getHeight(), false, false);
    spriteBatch.end();

}
}
```

[image]

And here's how it looks thereafter[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you updated your SpriteBatch to use the same camera that you are using with DebugRenderer?

Comment: Hello Rob, thans for your answer. I have done this debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);  But as you points out the SpriteBatch has no knowledge of the camera (matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. This is due to the fact rotations in OpenGL are done around the bottom left corner, whereas rotations in Box2D are done around mass center's body.
Rotating the texture around mass center body gives right physics/texture behavior.

Comment: If this is your answer, please accept it to remove this question from the Unanswered Questions list,

Comment: Sure how this is done? It is not automatic once I'd say the answer?

Comment: Click the tick next to your answer.