# Libgdx - difference between Box2DDebugRenderer.render and spritebatch.draw

Tags: android, libgdx, game-physics

I am trying to create a simple Android game using libGDX and physics.

As far as I can understand, we can "draw" physics body objects (box2d body objects) either by:

```
debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
```

or by something like:

```
  batch.begin();
  sprite = (Sprite) circleBody.getUserData();
  sprite.setPosition(circleBody.getPosition().x - (sprite.getWidth() /2) ,     circleBody.getPosition().y - (sprite.getHeight()/2));
  sprite.setSize(45*2, 45*2);
  sprite.draw(batch);
  batch.end();
```

Can someone explain me the difference between the two?
I think its not ideal to use `debugRenderer.render(...)` for release/production codes. Is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is very simple. The `Box2dDebugRenderer` is extremely simple to use. It basically requires just a single line of code (the one you already wrote in your question), and it will render simple shapes to visualize your Box2D `World`. It will render coloured squares, circles, lines and points for `Fixture`s, `Joint`s or `Contact`s.

The second approach you posted is completely selfmade. You can draw whatever you want for the `Body`. You can draw a simple shape yourself, or a sprite, or maybe an animation or even a 3D model. Maybe even nothing.

That's the "problem" with Box2D. The `World` you create is purely a physics world and Box2D does not know how to render anything, that's what you have to do yourself. A squared `Fixture` attached to a `Body` could be a wall, it could be a box or a door.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604982/box2ddebugrenderer-and-spritebatch-misplaced) other question on SO has a few pictures which show the difference when both rendering methods are used. (Unfortunately they are rendered on different places, which is what this quesion was about).

[image]

Comment: Can I use Box2dDebugRenderer for release codes or is it just for debugging purpose?

Comment: If all you want is simple rectangles, circles and lines, then of course you can use it in a release version. It is a very fast way of rendering the world.